# Can I plant a bush directly behind a lamp post?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Pretty much all is said in the title. Can I plant a bush directly behind a lamp post? Also, can I plant some on the sides? I'd like to know here rather than spend many thousand bells for no reason.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, your question has already been asked. Unfortunately it hasn't received answers yet.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn`t sure if that other question, if answered, would answer specifically what I'm being asked here. Neverless, I am conducting experiments today, and will have an answer to both questions by tomorrow.

Comment: That is awesome news!

Comment: You can't. I've tried, but they die out.